# I have a question(turtlebot - ROS). plz read

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI.
I 'm a university student in South Korea(Ulsan university)
Not good at English ㅜㅜ
I'm studying for turtlebot,
Do you have turtlebot api?
ex) Line tracer that can respond to as a sensor, etc
(Reactive code)

A lot of Googling, but could not get information about api

I found it was only these classes

http://gazebo.willowgarage.com/api/group__gazebo__sensors.html

input parameter in class

There are many difficulties in studying
Please teaching about the site

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39481/i-have-a-question(turtlebot---ros).-plz-read/) by [An-Suyoel](https://answers.ros.org/users/2900/an-suyoel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Turtlebot uses ROS. That means, the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials) are a good starting point to get familiar with the involved APIs. In addition, have a look at the [Turtlebot](http://ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot) page and the tutorials that are linked from there.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2